# How to make the 'more' link point to the post instead of the category list

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I'm using the List Category Posts plugin to list a certain categories posts on a page in my site.
The default 'more' link functionality is to point to a full list of the categories posts. I'd like to have a 'more' link after each post + excerpt which links to the specific full post. Can his be done?

Answer (score 1):

inside the loop, after your excerpt you can place a the following:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">more</a>
```

Comment: Chris, thanks for the reply. What file is the loop in?

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not familiar with the plugin that you're referring to, but I'm guessing that it would be called "category.php" or something similar.

When people refer to "the loop" they are referring to standard while loop that displays all the posts.
Here is a good reference: [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: This feature is not included in the plugin now. And I'm not sure you can use the loop because it uses the get_posts function http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts